# GzipReader each_line method missing in Rubinius

Tags: ruby, gzip, rubinius

I am trying to read a gzipped file using Zlib:GzipReader. This works as expected using ruby 1.9.3 but I am getting a `method_missing` error for `each_line` when using Rubinius.

Is there any way to read a gzipped file using Rubinius?

```
require 'zlib'

Zlib::GzipReader.open("lines.txt.gz").each_line { |line|
  puts "#{line}"
}

Kernel(Zlib::GzipReader)#each_line (method_missing) at kernel/delta/kernel.rb:81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Rubinius, you should consider opening an issue for it with the project.  However, this workaround should get you going:

```
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'

file = File.read("lines.txt.gz")
lines = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(file)).read
```

Comment: Yes, it appears to be undefined in Rubinius. I have opened up an issue with them. Thanks for the workaround.